# Laravel generate signed route for Nuxt JS front-end

Tags: php, laravel, nuxt.js

I'm using Laravel as an API for my Nuxt JS front-end project. My front-end has a URL structure like this:

- http://localhost:3000/omboarding/
- http://localhost:3000/onboarding/{signature}/company/
- http://localhost:3000/

When a user lands on my index onboarding page, they click a button, and I make a post request to my Laravel's function to generate a signed route. I then need to redirect the user to the company page, and check that the signature hash is valid, and if it is, allow the user to continue, eventually they also end up on the user page.

The problem, is my function generates a signature based entirely on my back-end API, and not my front-end routing at all, how can I resolve this or just pluck the signature part and validate it?

```php
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $signature = URL::signedRoute('onboarding.show', ['is_new_journey' => true]);

    return new ApiSuccessResponse($signature, [
        'message' => 'Onboarding process started.'
    ], 201);
}
```